# Bazel : How to set this item of BUILD.bazel file?

Tags: bazel

What does this mean in `Bazel`'s [documentation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go#generating-build-files):

> Add the code below to the BUILD or BUILD.bazel file in the root
>   directory of your repository. Replace the string after prefix with the
>   prefix you chose for your project earlier.
>
> ```
> load("@bazel_gazelle//:def.bzl", "gazelle")
>
> # gazelle:prefix github.com/example/project 
> gazelle(name = "gazelle")
> ```

There is a sentence "Replace the string after prefix with the prefix you chose for your project earlier", my project is `D:\workspace\www\go_work\src\golang_learning`,how to set it?

Answer (score 0):

The wording implies you chose a prefix earlier; it looks like the documentation could use a bit of improvement, especially for those new to go - I don't see anything above that explaining the prefix they're talking about.

One way to think of this prefix is "the part of the path remaining when you strip off `$GOPATH/src/`". Based on the path you provide, this should be `golang_learning`, so change the `gazelle:prefix` line to

```
# gazelle:prefix golang_learning
```

and you should be good to go.